# multiple criteria for an if statement

Tags: vb.net, logical-operators

I have a form with 3 text boxes, txt_customeracc, txt_customername, txt_customercontact

These 3 text boxes are optional and by default the text boxes will have "N/A" displaying on form load, but if a user enters information into one of them I want them to enter the information in the other two boxes also.

The code I am using is below

```
If txt_customername.Text <> "" Or txt_customername.Text <> "N/A" Or 
   txt_customercontact.Text <> "" Or txt_customercontact.Text <> "N/A" And
   txt_customeracc.Text = "" Or txt_customeracc.Text = "N/A" 
   Then error1 += vbNewLine & "Please enter a correct Customer Account Number"
```

So from the above code I am expecting that if a user enters information in either the txt_customername or the txt_customercontact text boxes but not in the txt_customeracc box the warning should then appear but currently the warning message is displaying regardless of whether information is or isn't entered in any of the boxes. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I was struggling with this but it seems that if I remove the "N/A" element from the query and amend the form so the boxes load blank it works perfectly, thankyou for your help Wingedpanther

Comment: Out of all the answers provided I can't believe no one is doing string comparison. What if user enters `n/a` this will pass through that check. Comparison would work here, ToLower or ToUpper, just a thought...

Comment: @Zaggler I edited my answer following your comment

Comment: @MartinVerjans Thanks for the edit, this was something I had seen right away in all the answers provided. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is operator precedence ?**

Your main problem here is that you have an issue with [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx). What is that ?

It is exactly the same issue as when doing calcuations, multiplication comes first, then comes addition. Well in VB .NET, `And` operator comes before `Or`, so what you have written in your code is evaluated as follow :

```
If txt_customername.Text <> "" Or 
   txt_customername.Text <> "N/A" Or 
   txt_customercontact.Text <> "" Or 
   (txt_customercontact.Text <> "N/A" And txt_customeracc.Text = "") Or 
   txt_customeracc.Text = "N/A" 
Then 
   error1 += vbNewLine & "Please enter a correct Customer Account Number"
End If
```

Since this is not really what you want, let's build this together :

- if `customername` **OR** `customercontact` is filled up

**AND**

- `customeracc` is empty

That would give us :

```
if (
    (txt_customername.Text <> "" Or txt_customername.Text <> "N/A") 'CustomerName is filled up
    Or
    (txt_customercontact.Text <> "" Or txt_customercontact.Text <> "N/A") 'Customer Contact is filled up
   )
   And
   (txt_customeracc.Text = "" Or txt_customeracc.Text = "N/A") 'Customer account is empty
Then 
  'Do whatever
End If
```

**Make it better, call a function**

Another problem here is readability, this code may have errors because it's hard to read, so hard to debug.

What we can do is build a function that will check if a textbox is empty :

```
Private Function IsEmpty(Tb As Textbox) As Boolean
    'Here we return true if tb.Text is empty or contains "N/A"
    Return Tb.Text = "" Or Tb.Text = "N/A"
End Function
```

So that would make this a bit more readable :

```
if (Not IsEmpty(txt_customername) Or Not IsEmpty(txt_customercontact)) 'CustomerName or Customer Contact is filled up
   And IsEmpty(txt_customeracc) 'Customer account is empty
Then 
  'Do whatever
End If
```

**Make it better (2), Compare the strings**

As stated by zaggler in his comment, here we don't use String Comparison. What if a user starts typing, then decides to put it back to N/A and writes it lowercase ("n/a") ? Well, we will make a mistake, believing that he did fill up the Textbox and you will end up searching for user "n/a" in your database, which is not a very good idea...

So let's [compare the String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx), make our function even better :

```
Private Function IsEmpty(Tb As Textbox) As Boolean
    'Here we return true if tb.Text is empty or contains "N/A" (or "n/a")
    Return Tb.Text = "" Or (String.Compare(Tb.Text, "N/A", True) = 0)
End Function
```

*Note*

You can see here the advantage of functions. I wrote it because I didn't want to change to `String.Compare()` six times... Whenever you have the same code twice, it should be a function...

Comment: Thanks Martin, that is a really simple explanation for a simple minded person (me) and is just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the user a proper error message telling him *what* he has missed to fill out you have to split the if statement into several parts.

First check if all text boxes contain any valid data.
If not you can skip further checks directly.
If one textbox contains data check each and set error accordingly.

```
If (txt_customername.Text = "" OrElse txt_customername.Text = "N/A") AndAlso
   (txt_customercontact.Text = "" OrElse txt_customercontact.Text = "N/A") AndAlso
   (txt_customeracc.Text = "" OrElse txt_customeracc.Text = "N/A") Then

    'No Error exit sub
    Exit Sub
End If

'This part is only reached if one textbox contains data
If (txt_customername.Text = "" OrElse txt_customername.Text = "N/A") Then
    error1 += vbNewLine & "Please enter a correct Customer Name"
End If

If (txt_customercontact.Text = "" OrElse txt_customercontact.Text = "N/A") Then
    error1 += vbNewLine & "Please enter a correct Customer Contact"
End If

If (txt_customeracc.Text = "" OrElse txt_customeracc.Text = "N/A") Then
    error1 += vbNewLine & "Please enter a correct Customer Account Number"
End If
```

As you can see I also recommend using short circuit `OrElse` and `AndAlso` which gives a littttttttle performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of filled fields.

```
   Dim numberFilled As Integer = 0

    If txt_customername.Text <> "" And txt_customername.Text <> "N/A" Then
        numberFilled += 1
    End If

    If txt_customercontact.Text <> "" And txt_customercontact.Text <> "N/A" Then
        numberFilled += 1
    End If

    If txt_customeracc.Text <> "" And txt_customeracc.Text <> "N/A" Then
        numberFilled += 1
    End If

    If numberFilled = 1 Or numberFilled = 2 Then
        error1 += vbNewLine & "Please enter a correct Customer Account Number"
    End If
```

Personally I would have a function IsValueEmpty that would check:

```
Function IsValueEmpty(ByVal value As String) As Boolean

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Or value = "N/A" Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

Could also Trim.

Comment: `IsValueEmpty` body can just be `Return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) OrElse value = "N/A"`

Answer (score 0):

You could have the relevant message part stored in the `Tag` property of each textbox and use Linq :

```
Dim customerTextBoxes = {txt_customeracc, txt_customername, txt_customercontact}

Dim messages = Aggregate customerTextBox In customerTextBoxes
               Where customerTextBox.Text = "" OrElse customerTextBox.Text = "N/A" 
               Select $"Please enter a correct {customerTextBox.Tag}")
               Into ToArray
```

Then just check it's length against the initial one and if they're not equal aggregate the message for display

```
If customerTextBoxes.Length <> messages.Length Then error1 = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, messages)
```